# Google calendar event creation with specific hours for start and end

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

Based on Google script running from a Google Sheet, I'm able to create an all-day event but have some challenges with setting an event for 1 hour. I'm sure it's a very silly question but perhaps someone can tell me where to add the reference to the start and end time/hour (not date)?

Here's my code:

```
var eventdate = '05/08/2020';
var eventstarttime = '10:00:00';
var eventaddress = 'test location';
 var endtime = eventtime + 3600000; // one hour duration
 var timeZone = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var calendarid = 'XXXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com';
  var eventdetails = 'test details';
  
  var event = {
       location: eventaddress,
       summary: (var1 + ' related to ' + var2), // summary is built for two variables
    start: {
      date: Utilities.formatDate(eventdate, timeZone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
   
    },
    end: {
      date: Utilities.formatDate(eventdate, timeZone, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
      },
        description: HTMLbody.getContent() // I'm using an HTML template to build a customs description based on other variables from the Sheet
  };
  event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarid);
```

Comment: [createEvent(title,startTime,endTime,actions)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createEvent(String,Date,Date,Object))

Comment: @Cooper - Thx. This method does look much simpler expect for the date formatting issue. My date is generated by a date-format question from a Google Form. It seems that it creates it in the following format: DD/MM/YYYY. How do I convert it a format that the system can relate to? Also, how do I append the hour, which is created by another question on the same form, time-format to HH:MM:SS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting Date and Hour to DateTime:

```
let d='DD/MM/YYYY'.split('/');
let t='HH:MM:SS'.split(':');
let dt=new Date(d[2],d[1]-1,d[0],t[0],t[1],t[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks. Our form is collected two question: 1. date, 2. hour. This is for ease of use for non-expert users. It seems that I've been able to tackle the Date field, i.e. convert it to a usable string. However, I cannot seem to tackle the Time field. It shows as 18:00:00 on the Sheet (which is indeed the hour inputed by the user) but when I use getValue on this cell I get Sat Dec 30 1899 17:39:20 GMT+0200 (IST). What does this mean and how do I convert it back to HH:MM:SS, so I can use it?

Comment: = Thanks again. I ended up using supporting cells inside the sheet itself. I simply "split" into separate cells for each part of the date and time. It works now. Thank you!